# htaccess Detect slash AND no slash in directory

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

With:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?pet=$1 [NC]
```

"www.domain.com/cat" works but "www.domain.com/cat/" doesn't (notice slash at the end).

How can I modify this rule to work with AND without the slash? Or do I need two rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just include an optional trailing slash in your regex:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?pet=$1 [L,QSA]
```

You can also use:

```
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?pet=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Works great! Whats the difference between ([\w-]+) and ([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+) ? With the latter I believe it's only allowing numbers, alphabet characters and the symbols '_' and '-'.

Comment: `\w` is same as `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` so `([\w-]+)` and `([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)` are exactly same.

Comment: Great to know, and shave off a few bytes from the file. Thank you for the fast and concise replies!